# Changing ic_launcher resource file don't have any effect in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

I want to change my icon, so after I change `ic_launcher`, I want my icon to be changed with the color, but the icon don't overwrite.

What should I do, after editing the `ic_launcher`, so my icon changes?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the ic_launcher in different resoultion folder i.e example hdpi,xhdpi etc. Change the things in all folders so that it will reflect the icon